# Android Animation - unfortunately program has stopped

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, animation

I'm writing an application on android... I'm wanna the first page of my app has an imageView & textView with an animation but my app has shown me this error: "Unfortunetly program has stopped"..
What's wrong? What should I've done?

src/PlantActivity.java:

```
package com.AdMd.Plant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PlantActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent i = new Intent(PlantActivity.this, FadeInActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

src/FadeInActivity.java

```
package com.AdMd.Plant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FadeInActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

    TextView txtMessage;
    ImageView img;

    // Animation
    Animation animFadein;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.page1);

        txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        // load the animation
        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.fade_in);

        // set animation listener
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

        // button click event
        //btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            //public void onClick(View v) {
                txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // start the animation
                txtMessage.startAnimation(animFadein);
                img.startAnimation(animFadein);
            //}
    //  });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Take any action after completing the animation

        // check for fade in animation
        if (animation == animFadein) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

res/anim/fade_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

res/layout/page1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:text="@string/app_info" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat messages is:

```
07-07 11:26:55.792: D/AndroidRuntime(1957): Shutting down VM
07-07 11:26:55.792: W/dalvikvm(1957): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AdMd.Plant/com.AdMd.Plant.PlantActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.AdMd.Plant/com.AdMd.Plant.FadeInActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.AdMd.Plant/com.AdMd.Plant.FadeInActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.AdMd.Plant.PlantActivity.onCreate(PlantActivity.java:14)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-07 11:26:55.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     ... 11 more
07-07 11:27:00.962: I/Process(1957): Sending signal. PID: 1957 SIG: 9
```

PlantManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.AdMd.Plant"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".PlantActivity" >
            <activity android:name=".FadeInActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" > </activity>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please include crash report..

Comment: I wrote it's error.. That is:Unfortunetly program has stopped!

Comment: That occurs due to many reasons. So please check logcat and copy the error here.

Comment: *have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?*

Comment: Add in manifest: `<activity android:name=".FadeinActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" > </activity>`

Comment: I don't change AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @PurpleDroid has already provided you a sample, you just need to add that to your Android Manifest within the <application> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at this error :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.AdMd.Plant/com.AdMd.Plant.FadeInActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-07 11:06:44.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
```

Did you initialise your Activity FadeInActivity in your AndroidManifest?

Every activity needs to be initialised in the AndroidManifest before it can run (:

EDIT :

You added the Activity within a nesting of another activity. It should be like this instead :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.AdMd.Plant"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".PlantActivity" >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FadeInActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it possible to include your AndroidManifest.xml in the sample above?

Comment: You have a typo in the AndroidManifest, it should be FadeInActivity, (the class name), instead of FadeinActivity

Comment: Yo dude, checkout the Edit (:

Comment: Sorry I copied your typo over, can you try and copy the XML over and see if it works?

Comment: What?I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Copy the EDIT i wrote and paste over your existing AndroidManifest

Comment: If you compare your code and mine, you put the <activity> for FadeInActivity within the <activity> for PlantActivity. It shouldnt be inside, it should be on its own outside the PlantActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your help and because of your patience :)